# How to represent a list which has the same difference between each number?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a list that looks like $(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{2},\frac{7\pi}{2}, \frac{9\pi}{2},\frac{11\pi}{2},\frac{13\pi}{2},\frac{15\pi}{2})$, is there anyway I can represent it with less writing? For example, is there any mathematical way I can say the first term, last term, and difference to represent the list.

Answer (score 0):

The series is $(a_n)_1^8$ where $a_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+\pi$

Answer (score 0):

A non-recursive solution is:
$$T_n = \frac{\pi}{2} + (n-1)\pi$$
and your sequence would be $(T_n)_1^8$